# Is a declaration of a variable inside a block also a definition?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, declaration, definition, c11

The C11 standard specifies in section 6.7/5 which declarations are also definitions:

> C11 6.7/5
>
> A definition of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier
>   that:
>
> — for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object;
>
> (...)

So is a declaration of a variable inside a block also a definition? For example:

```
void Bla(void) {
    int a; // Is this declaration also a definition?
}
```

I have found the following two answers on stackoverflow, which state that declarations of variables inside blocks are also definitions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4769638
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45695028/9771101

However, the answer provided by "Michael Burr" refers to 6.2.2/2 "Linkages of identifiers" in order to explain that variable declarations in block scope are also definitions. For me, his reference does not answer my question. The answer in the second link does not provide any reference to the C standard. Is there any other paragraph in the C standard which can be used as a reference to confirm those answers?

Please provide a reference to the C standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, a declaration of an "object" (the C standard avoids using the word "variable") at block scope is a definition, except when the declaration of that object uses the storage-class specifier `extern`, in which case it is not a definition.

Here is how to see that from the standard (all references are to [N1570](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html), which is the closest approximation to the official text of C2011 that is publicly available at no charge):

first, [6.2.2p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.2p6) says

> the following identifiers have no linkage: ... a block scope identifier for an object declared without the storage-class specifier extern.

second, [6.7p5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7p5) says

> A definition of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier that:
>   * for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object;

and finally, [6.2.4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4) which you will need to read in its entirety, but the most important bits are in paragraph 5 and 6:

> An object whose identifier is declared with no linkage and without the storage-class specifier static has automatic storage duration ... its lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in any way.

So, if you declare an object at block scope without `extern`, it has no linkage.  An object with no linkage has automatic storage duration, unless it was declared with `static`, in which case it has static storage duration instead, see the parts of 6.2.4 I didn't quote.  An object with automatic storage duration has storage reserved for it upon entry to the block it was declared within, and an object with static storage duration has storage reserved for it at program start (again, see the parts of 6.2.4 I didn't quote).  Therefore, any declaration of an object that gives it no linkage is a definition.

(A declaration of an object at block scope *with* `extern` gives it external linkage and is *not* a definition.  If you don't see why that is after reading through all of the sections I quoted and also [6.9](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9), please ask a new question specifically about that.)

Answer (score 4):

Section 6.2.2p6 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) states:

> In  the  set  of  translation  units  and  libraries  that 
>   constitutes  an  entire  program,  each declaration  of  a  particular
>   identifier  with external  linkage denotes  the  same  object  or
>   function.   Within  one  translation  unit,  each  declaration  of  an
>   identifier  with internal linkage denotes  the  same  object  or 
>   function.   **Each  declaration  of  an  identifier  with no linkage
>   denotes a unique entity.**

The part that's missing is section 6.2.2p6:

> The following identifiers have no linkage: an identifier declared to
>   be anything other than an  object  or  a  function;  an  identifier 
>   declared  to  be  a  function  parameter;  **a  block  scope identifier
>   for an object declared without the storage-class specifier extern.**

A variable declared inside of a block that does not have a storage class specifier (i.e. `static` or `extern`) has **no linkage**, and each declaration of a variable with no linkage is a unique object.  Because the declaration is unique, it also qualifies as a definition.

See also section 6.7p7:

> If  an  identifier  for  an  object  is  declared  with  no  linkage, 
>   the  type  for  the  object  shall  be complete  by  the  end  of  its
>   declarator,  or  by  the  end  of  its  init-declarator  if  it  has 
>   an initializer; in the case of function parameters (including in
>   prototypes), it is the adjusted type (see 6.7.6.3) that is required to
>   be complete.